# Microsoft.OData.ODataException when entering OData string parameter without enclosing single quotes in Swagger 'try it now'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, odata, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I migrated a web api project from asp.net v4 to asp.net core v6.
Microsoft AspNetCore OData: v8.08
Swashbuckle AspNetCore: v6.2.3

In the new environment I have to enclose the string parameters that are included in the OData route with single quotes, when I enter it in Swagger *try it out*.

If I omit the single quotes, the parameter in the request URL doesn't have enclosing single quotes and I get an exception:

https://localhost:7171/odata/test(id123)

*Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The key value (test) from request is not valid. The key value should be format of type 'Edm.String'.
---> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Expected literal type token but found token 'test'.
at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexerLiteralExtensions.ReadLiteralToken(ExpressionLexer expressionLexer)
at Microsoft.OData.ODataUriUtils.ConvertFromUriLiteral(String value, ODataVersion version, IEdmModel model, IEdmTypeReference typeReference)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Template.KeySegmentTemplate.TryTranslate(ODataTemplateTranslateContext context)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Template.KeySegmentTemplate.TryTranslate(ODataTemplateTranslateContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Template.DefaultODataTemplateTranslator.Translate(ODataPathTemplate path, ODataTemplateTranslateContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.ODataRoutingMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)*

In the asp.net v4 Swagger page I can enter the string parameters without enclosing single quotes.
And if I change my operation to Non-OData routing in my .net 6 project, I also can enter the string parameters without enclosing single quotes in Swagger *try it out*.

What can I do to make this work also with OData routing in my .net v6 project?

Code extract:

```
    [Route("odata")]
    public class testController : ODataController
    {
    
        [HttpGet("test({id})")]
        public IActionResult Get(string id)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you try to do is simply invalid OData. The End. If the key for the `Test` entity is a string, it *has* to be quoted. This has nothing to do with Swagger. What if you passed `test(123.45)`?  Or `test(4)` ? It's not OData's job to guess how to transform one type into another, or how the underlying implementation works. `test('id123')` has to be valid even if the service is implemented in Java, Go or Python

Comment: Of course I know that a string parameter in an OData URL needs enclosing single quotes. But I don't understand why they were automated added when I enter the string in the Swagger page in asp.net v4 but not in asp.netcore v6. Other additional string parameters that are not included in the OData route don't need to be enclosed with single quotes when entering it in the Swagger 'try it out' input fields. That is confusing for the users working with the Swagger page.